# How to open link to pdf file in new tab using html

Tags: html, file, pdf, hyperlink

I have an html page which contains link to open pdf file. however this link opens in adobe reader when i click on it. I have set target property to blank. but it doesn't work either.
I want to open this pdf file in new tab in the same window.

Comment: Agreed. Here is the link that explains those "User Preferences": [Force IE to open link in new tab](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/force-ie-to-open-link-in-new-tab/)

Answer (score 12):

`target="_blank"` is the right way - but if it opens in a new tab, a new window or the adobe reader depends on the users browser-settings and can't (and shouldn't!) be controlled by you.

Answer (score 3):

With my websites, I use:

`target="_tab"`  as most browsers are now aware that people want things to open in new tabs instead of new windows. I can confirm that this works for me in the following web browsers:

`Opera`, `Chrome`, `Flock`, `Firefox` and `Maxthon`.

However, it still does **not** work in any version of Internet Explorer, including their new beta version: 9. Apparently it comes down to "User Preferences" with Internet Explorer.

Determining which application opens a particular file format is currently, and should always be left up to the user, not the developer*.