# HTML PDF not opening

Tags: html, pdf

When I reference a .pdf in my webpage, the file doesn't open when I click on the link. I referenced the .pdf with the full path and the file is in the www folder.

When I hover over the link online, I can see that the link is to my .pdf on file but it doesn't open.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks (HTML newbie)

Edit 1 - reference:
`<a href="X:www\filename.pdf">Filename</a>`

Edit 2:
I tried the local links extension and it still isn't opening. I also tried `<a href="http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf">` and I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: Can you show your markup? And possibly your file structure too

Comment: <a href="X:www\filename.pdf">Filename</a>

Comment: Edit your question and put all that information in there instead, it's easier to read :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I don't have the rep to comment. But it looks like your ref structure could be wrong.

Try something like:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf">
```

**UPDATE:** Hmmm?

Have you tried just:

```
<a href="myfile.pdf">
```

Also, I found this which (while not directly relevant) has some discussions and links that may assist: [How to set height on PDF file when linked to from HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29749780/4806086)

^^ Ignore that - it really is more related to how the pdf opens.

**FURTHER:**

I am assuming the pdf file name has no spaces in it. I also assume you have a local pdf viewer.

So I had a look at a random website which had a pdf link as an example. When clicked, it opened the pdf in a new tab. I am on chrome.

You may be able to use that to figure out what is wrong.

Here is the page: http://www.staff.uwa.edu.au/procedures/communications/media/uwanews

Looking at the pdf for the first listed file, this was their link:

```
<a href="http://www.staff.uwa.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0004/2644285/119421_UWAnews-10-Dec-web.pdf" target="_blank">Issue-10-December-2014 [PDF File,&nbsp;2.0 MB]</a>
```

It looks like path should be enough, but you might want to add the target="_blank" to open in a new tab.

Maybe also see this, which shows that users set how a pdf is opened - perhaps the settings on your end need to be set up: [How to open link to pdf file in new tab using html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2947404/4806086)

Anyway, I wish you the best. Post your answer when figure it all out.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers block links to `file://` URLs from pages that aren't themselves on a `file://` URL, and in the same directory tree.

This is a security feature. There are workarounds that you can install locally so it works on one specific computer. See [this Mozillazine article.](https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/963224)